# Postman not sending data back from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]
postman returns a 404 error when i use this route handler which means the task can not be found. But when i console.log the task it appears in the command line. See picture below
[image]
Below is a snapshot from postman when i use the route handler
[image]

This is the code for the authentication(auth) middleware
[image]

The code below is the code in the task.js file. This file handles HTTP requests related to the task model

```
const express = require("express");
const Task = require("../models/tasks");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const router = new express.Router();

router.post("/tasks", auth, async (req, res) => {
  //const task = new Task(req.body);
  const task = new Task({
    ...req.body,
    owner: req.user._id
  });

  try {
    await task.save();
    return res.status(201).send(task);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    // return res.send(e);
  }
});

router.get("/tasks", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const allTasks = await Task.findOne({ owner: req.user._id });
    res.status(200).send(allTasks);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});

router.get("/tasks/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const task = await Task.findOne({ _id, owner: req.user._id.toHexString() });
    console.log(_id, req.user._id.toHexString(), task);
    if (!task) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
    res.send(task);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});

router.patch("/tasks/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
  const allowedUpdates = ["description", "completed"];
  const isValidOperation = updates.every(update =>
    allowedUpdates.includes(update)
  );

  if (!isValidOperation)
    return res.status(400).send({ error: "invalid updates!" });

  try {
    //const task = await Task.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new: true,runValidators: true});
    const task = await Task.findOne({
      _id: req.params.id,
      owner: req.user._id
    });

    if (!task) return res.status(404).send();
    updates.forEach(update => {
      task[update] = req.body[update];
    });
    await task.save();
    return res.send(task);
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

router.delete("/tasks/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const task = await Task.findOneAndDelete({
      _id: req.params.id,
      owner: req.user._id
    });

    if (!task) return res.status(404).send();
    res.send(task);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Please help
was expecting the task

Comment: could you show us auth middleware aswell and where you use the router

Comment: Okay will do that

Comment: Your auth middleware wont work. No matter if authenticated or not, `next()` will always be called.

Comment: @bill.gates thanks I did not notice that. I got rid of the second next() call. My code works well now